# Is it possible to add one UIButton object to multiple UIImageViews?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibutton, subview

I have a `scrollView` and inside this `scrollView`, there are various `PFImageView` objects.

I need a single `UIButton` object on every `PFImageView` (same place and same button) that will load a subView with the information of the image tapped.

Is this possible?

Comment: please edit the title and also try to make the question clearer..

Comment: My title has to remain the same I guess, since I am trying to set multiple actions to a single button. I guess I'll edit the content. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want multiple actions at the same time?

Comment: so you N imageViews and N buttons... why the duplicate actions?

Comment: Not at the same time. I have a ScrollView with 10 PFImageViews, in other words. 10 images. Each Image will have this same Button. and when you click on that button the Details (or information) of the imaged clicked will appear as as subview. That is why I need 1 button (the same in each image) to give me multiple actions.. In other words.. same action but different content. Is that clear? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a single control in multiple locations, it's that simple.
I saw your comment about not wanting to use a UICollectionView because it's not the design you're looking for, but I wonder what kind of design you want to create with UIScrollView only because UICollectionView doesn't works.

UICollectionView is not restrained to line/grid display of cells, but can be customized in a huge amounts of ways. You should watch the WWDC 2012 video "Introducing Collection Views" : at the end of it, some UICollectionView possibilities are shown and some of them are quite impressive.

Also, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ website is a good place to find custom controls and even inspiration for your own design.

This is a little digression from the original issue, but I really think that a collection of UIImageView within an UIScrollView can be created with a UICollectionView, especially if you want to add some controls within your "cells".

Comment: Since I am new to iOS I thought the collectionView was only set as a Grid. Thank you!!

Comment: If you're new to iOS development, I encourage you to watch some WWDC videos, they're very interesting. Also, a great tutorial website is http://www.raywenderlich.com  . And StackOverflow for detailed questions, of course.

Answer (score 1):

So, let me get this straight... You want to create only **one** button, place it on **multiple** `imageView`s and have it respond differently (depending on which `imageView` was tapped)?

In this case...
**No**, you can't have 1 button in N places.

But... you can create N button objects and have them all assigned to 1 single target method in which... you can have different functionality based on the button's tag.

PS: `UICollectionView` would be cleaner approach.

Comment: @adriennemhenry : what kind of functionality and UI are you trying to create? maybe a screenshot of what you want can help someone suggest something

Comment: Hey! Thanks!! ... I set N amount of buttons (got it going well enough) I know a `UICollectionView` might be cleaner, but I don't know how to set it up! (I'm an amateur). But I will certainly keep that in mind and start digging up information on how to set it up. I really appreciate your time. Thanks again!

Comment: @adriennemhenry : np :) fyi: setting up `collectionView` is very similar to setting up a `tableView` so the learning curve won't be too steep if you already know `tableView`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should use specific control events when adding actions to the button.

E.g. in my application i record/stop/cancel sound as long as user hold a button (drag out to cancel).. like a walkie talkie phone...

```
[recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordStart) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordStop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordCancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
```